# Fill a cell with alternative text when IMPORTRANGE cell is blank

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I am using the following formula to import data from one spreadsheet to another:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet1!N231")
```

In some cases the imported range is blank. I would like for these cells to say "TBC" on my new spreadsheet, instead of remaining blank.

I have tried to work in the `ISBLANK` command but am struggling with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
=IF(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet1!N231")<>"", IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Sheet1!N231"), "TBC")
```